# how to split the text using java script with )/

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I am facing the issue in splitting text using javascript. the string i have to split is as below

> `mobile)/index.m3u8`

And my output should be something as below

> mobile and index.m3u8

I tried with `.split("\\)");` but it's not able to split. Any help on this 
Thanks

Comment: how is `"\\)"` even close to `")/"`? both order and direction of / are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use split it will return value as array.
you can try this

```js
var str = 'mobile)/index.m3u8';
console.log(str.split(')/'));
```

Or if you want to replace `mobile)/index.m3u8` with `mobile and index.m3u8`.
just use the

```
str.replace(')/',' and ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` method to replace )/ with space.

```js
var str = "mobile)/index.m3u8";
console.log(str.replace(')/',' and '));
```

Answer (score 0):

simple `split(')/')` and `join(' and ')`

```js
var a ='mobile)/index.m3u8';

console.log(a.split(')/').join(' and '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two option to do this.

**Option 1**

You can use split or join method

```js
var str = 'mobile)/index.m3u8';
var finalString = str.split(')/').join(' and ');
console.log(finalString);
```

Output: `mobile and index.m3u8`

**Option 2**

You can use replace method

```js
var str = 'mobile)/index.m3u8';
var finalString = str.replace(')/', ' and ');
console.log(finalString)
```

Output: `mobile and index.m3u8`

As my point of view **option 1** is better because currently, you have string `)\` only at one place but if you have same string more than one place than **option 2** will not work for you.

```js
var str = "mobile)/index)/.m3u8";
var finalString = str.replace(')/',' and ');
console.log(finalString);
```

Output - `mobile and index)/.m3u8`

```js
var str = "mobile)/index)/.m3u8";
var finalString = str.split(')/').join(' and ');
console.log(finalString);
```

Output - `mobile and index and .m3u8`

It may be helpful for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to split that string by ')/' then you should do `.split(')/');` instead of `.split("\\)");`. There was a mistake there.